# After deleting a comment, most buttons won't work until you refresh the page

Tags: bug, status-norepro, comments

If you deleted a comment while using Edge browser, none of the action buttons work (up/down vote, close, flag, etc.) until you refresh the page.

I have tested this with Chrome/IE11 and I do not see the same behavior. I am using Windows 10 with November update.

Comment: Can someone confirm this?

Comment: I think you are the only person in the world using edge.